# Linking Matlab with C#

Tags: c#, matlab

Is there a way that we can link a GUI C# program with any 'm' file in a way that we can give the 'm' file an input from the C# program?

For example, the m file here is a function that rotates any given images by 'a' degree, where the degree is an input from the C# program.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi! Did you link to the m file? you mention 'the m file here'

Comment: a quick google revela many - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594636/Using-Matlab-from-a-Csharp-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate MATLAB from your C# GUI application using COM, see https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html.

See as well the following code example:

```
MLApp.MLApp m = new MLApp.MLApp();
double x = 0.5;
m.PutWorkspaceData("x", "base", (object)x);
m.Execute("y=sin(x);"); // here you could execute your m-file
double y = m.GetVariable("y", "base");
m.Quit();
```

Make sure you add a reference to `Matlab Application (Version x.x) Type Library` in your C# GUI application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply , but we have an issue here >> firstly the function  that we implemented in matlab is not a built-in function , it is a function written by ourselves where many transformations were applied , Secondly Can you please show me the case where y is an image , because in this case it simply a boolean variable >> And thanks again for your reply :)))

Comment: @Ahmedb 1st: you can execute your function in `m.Execute("y=yourfunction(x)")`. 2nd: image = boolean variable? or 2d array of bolean variable? Anyway see the help for `m.GetVariable` https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getvariable.html and the help for `m.GetFullMatrix` https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfullmatrix.html.